The hardware decoding was successful, but the hw_frames_ctx in the received frame is empty
I tried to use QSV hardware decoding under ffmpeg, using the integrated graphics 730 on my computer. Here's the code I used to initialize the decoder
const AVCodec* codec = NULL;
int ret;
int err = 0;
// Create the QSV hardware device.
    ret = av_hwdevice_ctx_create(&hw_device_ctx, AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_QSV, "auto", NULL, 0);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        char error_string[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
        av_make_error_string(error_string, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, ret);
        LError("Error creating QSV device: {}", error_string);
        return NULL;
    }
 // Search for QSV decoders, either for H.264 or H.265.
    codec = avcodec_find_decoder_by_name(codec_name);
    if (!codec)
    {
        LError("Failed to find QSV decoder.");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Creating a decoder context and associating it with the hardware device.
    decoder_ctx = avcodec_alloc_context3(codec);
    if (!decoder_ctx)
    {
        ret = AVERROR(ENOMEM);
        LError("Failed to allocate decoder context.\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    decoder_ctx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;  
    decoder_ctx->opaque = &hw_device_ctx;
    decoder_ctx->get_format = get_format;
// Open the decoder.
    if ((ret = avcodec_open2(decoder_ctx, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    {
        LError("Failed to open decoder: %d\n", ret);
        return NULL;
    }

    parser_ctx = av_parser_init(avcodec_find_encoder_by_name(codec_name)->id);

The following is the process of decoding using the decoder:
AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    AVFrame* dstFrame = av_frame_alloc();
    res = avcodec_send_packet(decoder_ctx, pkt);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    int num = 0;
    while (res >= 0)
    {
        res = avcodec_receive_frame(decoder_ctx, frame);

        if (res == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || res == AVERROR_EOF)
        {
            //if (res == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) 
            //{
            //   LInfo("AVERROR(EAGAIN):");
            //}
            //if (res == AVERROR_EOF) 
            //{
            //  //  LInfo("AVERROR_EOF");
            //}
           // av_frame_unref(frame);
            break;
        }
        else if (res < 0)
        {
          //  av_frame_unref(frame);
            return;
        }


        frameNumbers_++;
        if (frame->hw_frames_ctx == NULL)
        {
            LError("hw_frames_ctx is null");
            LError("avcodec_receive_frame return is {}", res);
        }

My issue is that I've successfully decoded the video. The return value of avcodec_receive_frame is 0, and the width and height of the AVFrame are the same as the input video stream.
However,** the hw_frames_ctx field of the AVFrame is empty**. Why would this happen in a successful hardware decoding scenario?
Could it be due to some incorrect configurations? I've set up a get_format function like this
static enum AVPixelFormat get_format(AVCodecContext *avctx, const enum AVPixelFormat *pix_fmts)
{
    while (*pix_fmts != AV_PIX_FMT_NONE) {
        if (*pix_fmts == AV_PIX_FMT_QSV) {
            DecodeContext *decode = (DecodeContext*)avctx->opaque;
            AVHWFramesContext  *frames_ctx;
            AVQSVFramesContext *frames_hwctx;
            int ret;
            /* create a pool of surfaces to be used by the decoder */
            avctx->hw_frames_ctx = av_hwframe_ctx_alloc(decode->hw_device_ref);
            if (!avctx->hw_frames_ctx)
                return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
            frames_ctx = (AVHWFramesContext*)avctx->hw_frames_ctx->data;
            frames_hwctx = (AVQSVFramesContext*)frames_ctx->hwctx;
            frames_ctx->format = AV_PIX_FMT_QSV;
            frames_ctx->sw_format = avctx->sw_pix_fmt;
            frames_ctx->width = FFALIGN(avctx->coded_width, 32);
            frames_ctx->height = FFALIGN(avctx->coded_height, 32);
            frames_ctx->initial_pool_size = 32;
            frames_hwctx->frame_type = MFX_MEMTYPE_VIDEO_MEMORY_DECODER_TARGET;
            ret = av_hwframe_ctx_init(avctx->hw_frames_ctx);
            if (ret < 0)
                return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
            return AV_PIX_FMT_QSV;
        }
        pix_fmts++;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "The QSV pixel format not offered in get_format()\n");
    return AV_PIX_FMT_NONE;
}

But I also noticed that even though I set decoder_ctx->get_format = get_format; this function is not being executed later on.
I observed that my GPU is also being utilized during program execution, indicating a successful hardware decoding. My subsequent goal is to render a frame from this decoded AVFrame. It seems like the hw_frames_ctx of the AVFrame is a texture handle on the GPU. I wish to directly use this field for D3D11 rendering and display it on the screen.
My questions are:

Is the hw_frames_ctx field empty in the case of successful hardware decoding?
Does it represent a texture handle on the GPU?
If my rendering approach is wrong, how can I correctly render this AVFrame using D3D11?

